# Why i getting None In addition to the Output?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I don't understand why i getting ***None*** in output of this code ?

```
class mobile:
    def __init__(self, name, brand):
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand

    # def get_name(self):
    #     return self.name

class cpu(mobile):
    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)


brand = cpu("Intel","Sony")
print(brand.get_name())
```

The output is :

```
Intel
None
```

Comment: You're getting `None` because you are printing the return value of `brand.get_name()`, and you don't return a value from that function, in which case python treats the return value as `None`.

Comment: adding on to Nick's comment, instead of `print(self.name)` use `return self.name`